# NoClassDefFoundError when attempting to run Java Spark app on command line

Tags: java, apache-spark, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror, deploying

I'm trying to run an application using spark on java, but when I try `mvn package; mvn exec:java` I keep running into a NoClassDefFoundError.

When I tried running the program in PowerShell and in Intellij and keep getting the same error(below). when I remove a bunch of maven dependincies, the error goes away and the servlet runs on localhost.

error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.<clinit>(SessionHandler.java:140)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyFactory.create(EmbeddedJettyFactory.java:43)
    at spark.embeddedserver.EmbeddedServers.create(EmbeddedServers.java:65)
    at spark.Service.lambda$init$2(Service.java:497)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionIdListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

dependencies that I removed from the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.2</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

the servlet runs correctly with just the spark dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

but if I add any more the exception occurs

Comment: Update: It's just the edu.stanford.nlp dependencies that are causing the issue

Comment: It might be some dependency issue,  some where you required some particular version jar,

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! the sparkjava dependency required 5 more dependencies to function, which can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sparkjava/spark-core/2.9.1